# let statement and outer join in LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, sql, .net, linq

How to use the let statement in outer join of LINQ to SQL?

Something like below,

```
from a in tableA
from b in tableB.where(o =>  a.Key == o.Key).DefaultIfEmpty() //outer join
let x = b.objectBB  
where b != null && x != null && x.FilterCode == "X"
```

So,

> 1. Does the above query is fine?
> 2. Will the 'let' fail if 'b' is null ?
> 3. what will happen with the where clause on 'x'? Does this filter work fine?

Any better way to achieve this also much welcome.!

Comment: This will definitely fail in linq to object because `let` gets translated into `select` *ahead* of the `where` clause, but good chances are that it's going to work fine in linq to sql.

Comment: Is it the one you are looking for http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/linq/UXPF181012-SQL-Joins-with-C

Comment: Well: a) C# is case sensitive; `where` should be `Where` when you're trying to call the method; b) if b were null, how would you expect `o.Key` to match the where clause to start with? c) you don't have a select or group clause at the end of your query... d) have you *tried* it? If you want to know if a query is "fine" the *first* thing you should do is try it. If it works in a quick test, then it *might* be fine (although that's no guarantee) - but if it fails to compile (as this will) then it clearly *isn't* fine.

Comment: @Jon skeet: Yes, I tested it (there is a 'select  a' at the end, i missed to add here) and it is fetching the expected result. But I am not sure whether its a right way of querying or any better way of doing this.

Comment: Well as I mentioned, that code won't compile anyway due to `where` vs `Where`... which makes me wonder what *else* is different in your real code. But this is really only a left outer join - is that what you wanted? I would be reluctant to use the query in its current form (after fixing the compiler error) because it's "logically" wrong - it would fail under LINQ to Objects, for example, if `b` were ever null. (I see now how it could be, and retract my point b from the earlier comment.) But as Brett notes, if you require `b` to be non-null, you're just looking for an inner join (more)

Comment: ... and if you're only selecting `a`, why are you performing a join at all? Just use `where tableB.Any(b => b.Key == a.Key && b.objectBB != null && b.objectBB.FilterCode == "x")`

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me that if you want both sides to be not null, don't you just want an inner join?

```
from a in tableA
join b in tableB on a.Key equals o.Key
where b.FilterCode == "X"
```